# migrating from php to node : asynchronous in loop

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sqlite, migrate

I'm getting in trouble to migrate my website from PHP to Node.js.

I'm actually using SQLite3 along with the Spatialite extension to show some layers on an OpenLayers map. Users choose which layers they want to show using checkboxs in a menu [ thematics => rubrics => layers ], something like :

```
MY THEMATIC 
    MY RUBRIC
        ONE LAYER
        ANOTHER LAYER
        STILL ANOTHER LAYER
    ANOTHER RUBRIC ...
ANOTHER THEMATIC ...
```

A JSON file describes the content of this menu :

```
{
    "MY THEMATIC": {
        "MY RUBRIC": [ 
            "ONE LAYER", "ANOTHER LAYER", "STILL ANOTHER LAYER"
        ],
        "ANOTHER RUBRIC": ...
    },
    "ANOTHER THEMATIC"
}
```

Each layer is linked to another JSON file describing the layer ( layer and legend color,  which table in the database, stroke width, etc... )
When generating the menu, I have to check if layers are valid ( database exists, table exists, query must return at least one row ! ).

If a layer is not valid, it isn't shown in the menu.

If all layers in a rubric are not valid, the rubric doesn't appear in the menu.

If all rubrics are not showing any layer, the thematic doesn't appear too.

My problem is that I'm actually using SQLite3 in a blocking way in PHP but database queries are asynchronous in Node.js. So I've tried to do this with callbacks, working, but code is really ugly and difficult to read/understand. I looked at promises but I didn't get it to work. Here is the algorithmic PHP version of my source code generating the menu :

```
$out = Array(); // Output array to fill in
$thematics = json_decode("..."); // My JSON file read and stored in a PHP array

foreach ($thematics as $thematicName => $rubrics) {
    $out[$thematicName] = Array();
    $flagThematic = true; // Flag controlling if the thematic contains at least one rubric

    foreach ($rubrics as $rubricName => $layers) {
        if ($rubricName == "rubric name to exclude") {
            continue;
        }
        $out[$thematicName][$rubricName] = Array();
        $flagRubric = true; // Flag controlling if the rubric contains at least one valid layer

        foreach ($layers as $layer) {
            // isValid 
            // This function query the database to check the layer validity
            // THIS is the asynchronous one in node.js
            if (!isValid($layer)) { 
                continue;
            }
            $out[$thematicName][$rubricName][] = ["..."]; // add layer info such as legend, name ...
            $flagRubric = false;
        }
        if ($flagRubric === true) {
            // No layer in this rubric, deleting the rubric
            unset($out[$thematicName][$rubricName]);
        } else {
            $flagThematic = false;
        }
    }

    if ($flagThematic === true) {
        // No rubric in this thematic, deleting the thematic
        unset($out[$thematicName]);
    }
}

return $out;
```

Do you have any advice to help me to turn this code into Node.js ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

I tried something like that, using bluebird (https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) :

```
function generateMenu(callback) {
    var out = {};
    Promise.map(Object.keys(thematics), function (thematicName) {
        out[thematicName] = {};
        return {
            rubrics: thematics[thematicName],
            thematicName: thematicName
        };
    }).map(function (res) {
        Promise.map(Object.keys(res.rubrics), function (rubricName) {
            if (rubricName === "rubric name to exclude") {
                return null; // don't really know how to do here, I think I'm doing it wrong
            }

            out[res.thematicName][rubricName] = {};
            return {
                layers: them[res.thematicName][rubricName],
                thematicName: thematicName,
                rubricName: rubricName
            };
        }).map(function (res) {
            // Doing more stuff with layers then call the main callback
            callback(out);
        });
    });
```

But I think I'm totally going wrong, I'm thinking about flags and cie as if I was using PHP. I guess I didn't get the "node logic" programming.

Comment: Please share what you have tried and what didn't work then we can help you fix your issues.

Comment: Hi, I added some details into my original message. Thanks for the help